# Assuming vortex defect pinning is equal, and number of tubes are equal should longer flux tubes lead to stronger pinning?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, superconductivity, vortex

Suppose you have two superconductors that resemble rectangular prisms with identical width and length. The first superconductor call it $A$ is shorter than $B$ visualized below:

[image]

[image]

Now both $A$ and $B$ are somehow carefully cooled and pinned over an identical magnet from an identical height so that they have flux tubes passing through them. In particular the have the exact same number of flux tubes and the same distribution/layout of flux tubes. The only difference being that of course the flux tubes of $B$ are much longer than $A$. (I acknowledge this experimentally might be impossible to realize for bulk rectangular prisms or at least extremely difficult)

[image]

[image]

Is it more difficult to separate the superconductor $B$ from the magnet than $A$? Conceptually you would think that since all other parameters are equal that in order to move $B$ the "amount" of flux tube that needs to be re-arranged to move $B$ relative to the magnet is much more than $A$ and therefore much more energy is expended in moving $B$ than $A$. At least [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137815/) which states "The energy you supply by the force [to move the superconductor] is transformed into changing the flux tube configuration..." gives that impression. But while that feels intuitive to me I have no way of being sure and I would like someone could shed some more clarity on the matter.